# Securing videos in the raw folder android

Tags: android, aes

I want to include videos in the raw folder of android in my paid app, now I don't want a determined hacker to get these files and benefit from them. So I thought about encrypting the videos with AES and then store them in raw folder, but what about the key where do I put that? I know there is no bullet proof way but I want to make it very hard for a hacker to reach the videos.

Answer (score 1):

Use android keystore: 
https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore

This only works for API level 18 and above.

Comment: But should I store the key programmatically?

Comment: What? Use the above to generate and store keys that you need. I am not sure what you are trying to ask.

Comment: I encrypt the videos and include them packaged with my app. Now they need the key to be opened where do I store the key safely. I don't want to hardcode the key through code.

Comment: Did you click the link above? It tells you how to store the key.

Comment: I understand what you posted in the link, I am not encrypting the files through code.

Comment: the files are already encrypted in the and added to the raw folder.

Comment: Where are you encrypting the video files?

Comment: I create the videos on macbook and encrypt them using terminal using AES algorithm.

Comment: How about storing the encrypted keys in a remote database somewhere and giving the keys to your "paid users" when they enter the correct password? Or you can just encrypt your video files in android and use the service I linked above.

Comment: it is meaningless to encrypt video using android, if it is already not encrypted it can be hacked.

Comment: There are no methods that are completely foolproof. The above method is safe given that you use proper precaution when setting up the database and the connections to the database (hint: things like firestore). Also, of course if you store the unencrypted video in storage it is meaningless. Not sure what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

**Way 1:** you can add some data at the first of video file and store it in raw folder. when you want use it you can remove the data you added and play the video. or you can add some bits in certain different points of video file and remove them when you wanna use it.

**Way 2:** or as you sayed you can encrypt it and for storing the key do not hardcode it.
you can write a function that with some mathematical operation make the string. this will make the work harder for the hacker.
a sample function could be this

```
fun createKey(rem: Long): String {
    var v = rem
    val builder = StringBuilder()
    while(v > 0) {
        builder.append((33 + v % 94).toChar())
        v /= 3
    }
    return builder.toString()
}
```

you store a long value into your code and when you want to use it, pass it to createKey and use returned value as key

Comment: Your first and second way are both vulnerable to decompilation. Obfuscation is not security.

Comment: @Steven you're right these ways are vulnerable against decompilation. but there is no fully secure way for stored data in client side especially when data is in apk file. so what we can just do is make it harder for attackers.